# Terminate a process by its name in Python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

Lets assume that i am starting a process in python with the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f(name):
     print ('hello ', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     p = Process(target=f,name = "Process-1", args=('bob',))
     p.start()
```

Now,i want to terminate the process.I can simply do:

```
p.terminate()
```

However, i would like to terminate the process by its name.Is that possible?

Comment: How about you store your `Process` objects in a dictionary when you create them? `process_dict['Process-1'] = p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you need to store a *map between your process objects and their names*. Using an helper function it makes your code even easier to read (IMO):

```
def terminate(procname):
    return pmap[procname].terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     pmap = {}
     pname = "process-1"
     p = Process(target=f,name = pname, args=('bob',))
     pmap[pname] = p
     p.start()
```

Then to terminate:
`terminate(pname)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.